# Internal hard drive connected by usb no longer displays in Disk Management. How to get the drive to show without deleting it's data?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I bought this: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004RORMF6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004RORMF6)
3TB internal hard drive to back-up data across multiple computers. When I connected the sata cable to USB, the hard-drive did not automatically show up in Windows 8 or Linux. However, from Windows I found the drive through: Computer Management --> Disk Management and then: applyed GPT to it, formatted the drive in NTFS and mounted it to my Desktop.
I was able to back-up data from the folder I mounted, but the drive still didn't show up  alongside Windows (C:) or This PC in File Explorer. I thought the data I was backing-up was just making a copy, but when the back-up finished, all those files were deleted from my computer. I already disconnected the USB cord between the hard drive and the computer, and when I plugged the drive back in, I could no longer see it in Computer Management --> Disk Management. Why can't I find it any more? How do I display the drive and it's contents again like a normal external hard-drive? I plugged the drive into a chromebook, and the chromebook had a notification saying "removable device connected". I found the drive in Files, but the chromebook wanted me to format the drive. That seemed strange since chromebook is compatible with NTFS. What went wrong? How do I get the data I backed-up back?